# JSON.parse unexpected token NODE

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Using `client.on('data', function(data){})` A node socket passes in the following data:

```
{
 "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 "result": {
           "Name": "MyGain",
           "Controls": [
                        {
                         "Name": "gain",
                         "String": "-18.0dB",
                         "Value": -18,
                         "Position": 0.68333333
                        },
                        {
                         "Name": "mute",
                         "String": "unmuted",
                         "Value": 0,
                         "Position": 0
                        }
                       ]
            },
 "id": "upd"
```

}

using `JSON.parse(data)` results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 201`

If I pass the string directly all works well.

Thanks in advance.#

EDIT1:

My Code:

```
this.client = new net.Socket();
this.client.setEncoding('utf8');
this.client.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('raw:' + data);
var dataj = JSON.parse(data);
// console.log(b);
if (dataj.id == "upd") {
    console.log("UPDATE MESSAGE");
} else {
    console.log('unknown:' + data);
}
// client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});
```

It works if:

```
this.client = new net.Socket();
this.client.setEncoding('utf8');
this.client.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('raw:' + data);
var dataj = JSON.parse({"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"Name":"MyGain","Controls":[{"Name":"gain","String":"-65.0dB","Value":-65.0,"Position":0.29166665},{"Name":"mute","String":"unmuted","Value":0.0,"Position":0.0}]},"id":"upd"});
// console.log(b);
if (dataj.id == "upd") {
    console.log("UPDATE MESSAGE");
} else {
    console.log('unknown:' + data);
}
// client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});
```

EDIT2:

Electron environment connected to local socket server. No control of servers output

Comment: JSON.parse is working fine. Can you create a code-snippet using `<>` icon at the top so that we can replicate this issue?

Comment: Its running in node and requires a socket connection, i've attached the full code in an edit

Comment: Better to `console.log(data)` to see what data exactly is. A string containing exactly the above block quoted code or ...?

Comment: the snippet of JSON i'm trying to decode is copied straight from the console. When copying the console print into a static variable all works well.

Comment: After this line `console.log('raw:' + data);` can you tell the output of `console.log('typeof:' + typeof data);`

Comment: sure: typeof:string

Comment: you are parse `string` into json format which is already in json format. no need to parse.

Comment: It will not work if you use  var dataj = JSON.parse({"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"Name":"MyGain","Controls":[{"Name":"gain","String":"-65.0dB","Value":-65.0,"Position":0.29166665},{"Name":"mute","String":"unmuted","Value":0.0,"Position":0.0}]},"id":"upd"}); this is also error ,You are converting JSON to JSON again

Comment: i thought json.parse was to convert json strings to objects?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
this.client = new net.Socket();
this.client.setEncoding('utf8');
this.client.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('raw:' + data);
var dataj = data
// console.log(b);
if (dataj.id == "upd") {
   console.log("UPDATE MESSAGE");
 } else {
  console.log('unknown:' + data);
 }
 // client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});
```

Comment: So my lack of understanding is that as its already in the correct format by re-assigning a variable JS automatically creates it as an object? Doing the above however always evaluates to unknown case and dataj type is still string

Comment: data is already in the correct format and you can use it directly without parse and without dataj

this.client.on('data', function(data) {
if (data.id == "upd") {
   console.log("UPDATE MESSAGE");
 } else {
  console.log('unknown:' + data);
 }
});

Comment: doing as you say when i simply console.log(data.id) i get undefined

Comment: you can console.dir(data) and you can see the attributes of your data, maybe the data havent and attribute called id

Comment: console.dir(data) and send to me the result

Comment: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"Name":"MyGain","Controls":[{"Name":"gain","String":"-49.0dB","Value":-49.0,"Position":0.42500001},{"Name":"mute","String":"muted","Value":1.0,"Position":1.0}]},"id":"upd"}

Comment: Though i belive i have solved it. removing \0 from the data from the socket and then parsing works

Comment: you have to emit data in json format
io.to(id).emit('data', {id: 'udp'});
and you can access to id simply data.id

Comment: if the value is string like that
io.to(id).emit('data', "{id: 'udp'}");
you have to parse data into json format using JSON.parse
and you can access to id using data.id